# Rotation with $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with center at the origin.

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you make a rotation with $\frac{\pi}{3}$ with center at the origin into   a linear function of z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with complex numbers, $e^{i\pi/3}$ represents rotation by the angle $\pi/3$, whence $f(z) = e^{i\pi/3}z$. In general, if you want to translate first by some fixed complex number $b$, and then apply a rotation, the result is the same as first translating and then applying the rotation. So, your transformation would be $f(z) = e^{i\pi/3}(b+z)$.

If you are working with vectors in $\Bbb R^2$, then the rotation matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\pi/3 & -\sin\pi/3 \\
\sin\pi/3 & \cos\pi/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
rotates vectors about the origin by $\pi/3$. Then, $f(x) = Ax$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working with complex number. How about "Translation along vector (2, -1), then rotation with angle pi/2 with center at
the origin."

Comment: @user368743 I updated my answer to address your second question.